# VsInstr performance profiling

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, performance, profiling

I have a problem with building performance profile for my .net web app

See my steps below:

1) Setup global variables

> VSPerfCLREnv /traceon
>       VSPerfCLREnv /globaltranceon

2) Instrument assemblies

> vsinstr "path to my assembly"

3) Restart iis

> iisreset

4) Start profiling

> VSPerfCmd /start:trace /output:traceoutput.vsp

5) Open app in browser, perform some actions on it

6) Stop profiling

> VSPerfCmd /shutdown

It creates the file traceoutput.vsp, but when I try to open it in visual studio, it whows "Error Error VSP1734 : File contains no data: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Team Tools\Performance Tools\traceoutput.vsp" message.

I was successfull in console application profiling. So, I have this problem only for assemblies in web app.

Comment: It is not ubuntu :). It is microsoft visual studio 2008.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've resolved this issue. I just forgot to specify the user.
I have had to write

```
VSPerfCmd /start:trace /output:traceoutput.vsp /user:ASPNET
```